# handle single quotes in search

Tags: java, oracle, struts2

How would I make a query statement with the single quotes in java. When i search a word with single quotes it show s no record to display

for example i have a name D'costa how would i search this using java

```
 getSearchByUserSQL.append("SELECT * FROM SID_USERS  ");
    getSearchByUserSQL.append("WHERE lower(FIRSTNAME) like  ? 
          OR lower(LASTNAME) like  ?");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape `'` with `\'`. Here `\` is a escape character.
You can use [String.replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) to replace `'` with `\'`.

EscapeSequence in Java:

```
\ b    /* \u0008: backspace BS */
\ t    /* \u0009: horizontal tab HT */
\ n    /* \u000a: linefeed LF */
\ f    /* \u000c: form feed FF */
\ r    /* \u000d: carriage return CR */
\ "    /* \u0022: double quote " */
\ '    /* \u0027: single quote ' */
\ \    /* \u005c: backslash \ */
```

[Doc Link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6)

Comment: Can u explain how to escape in java

Comment: use `\'` where you want to use `'`.

Answer (score 4):

while you *can* try and manually escape all strings its a lot of work and its difficult (different DBs may have different escaping rules). as further evidence that you shouldnt do it - look at apahe commons lang - they dropped support for escaping SQL between 2.* and 3.* for exactly that reason.

so instead, if you make your query into a [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html), you could then use [PreparedStatement.setParameter(int, String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setString%28int,%20java.lang.String%29) to insert your dynamic values instead of the placeholders and the JDBC driver will do all of your escaping for you. so:

```
String myQuery = "SELECT * FROM SID_USERS WHERE lower(FIRSTNAME) like :1 OR lower(LASTNAME) like :2";
PreparesStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(myQuery);
ps.setParameter(1,"Mickey");
ps.setParameter(2,"Mouse");
results = ps.execute();
```

Comment: The link is not opening for me

Comment: @jackyesind - working fine for me. its basically just the j2se 6 javadoc

Comment: +1. But regarding the comment, if it's 6, it should be Java SE 6, not J2SE 6 anymore ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Standard_Edition#Nomenclature.2C_standards_and_specifications ). The 2 is gone :)

Answer (score 1):

In Java, you need to escape the single quote with a backslash.  And for Oracle, you need to escape a single quote with a single quote.  So `\'\'` should do the trick, so in PL/SQL, it turns into `''`, which becomes `'` in the end.

```
getSearchByUserSQL.append("SELECT * FROM SID_USERS  ");
getSearchByUserSQL.append("WHERE lower(FIRSTNAME) like \'PETE\'\'S\' OR lower(LASTNAME) like \'REPEAT\'\'S\'");
```

Would find "pete's" and "repeat's" as first names.  Just giving the single quotes as literals for an example within a PL/SQL string.  It's called "String Inception"